# How to neo4j server using popoto js

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to run popoto js example but not working.
code:
 popoto.rest.CYPHER_URL = "http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit";
popoto.rest.AUTHORIZATION = "Basic " + btoa("neo4j:password");

But the cypher url not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the password portion of `popoto.rest.AUTHORIZATION = "Basic " + btoa("neo4j:password");` to the password of the neo4j server. This assumes that the default username is still neo4j.